# How to get cypress.io to swipe ionic ion-item-sliding to the left?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic4, cypress

I have a small ionic 4 (vue) app with an `ion-list` which includes `ion-item-sliding`:
here is how the code looks

**HTML**

```
<ion-item-sliding v-for="day in month.days" v-bind:key="day.day">
    <ion-item
      :id="'times-item-'+day.day+'-'+month.name.toLowerCase()+'-'+month.year"
      @click="openAddEditModal(day)"
    >
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="4">
            <ion-label :color="switchLabelColor(day)">
              <div id="times-item-day-weekday">{{ day.weekday }}.</div>
              <div id="times-item-day-day" class="bigger">
                {{ day.day }}
              </div>
            </ion-label>
          </ion-col>

          <ion-col size="4" v-if="getDayEntry(day)">
            <ion-text
              id="times-item-start-end-time"
              v-if="isWork(getDayEntry(day).type)"
            >
              {{ formatTime(getDayEntry(day).start) }} -
              {{ formatTime(getDayEntry(day).end) }}
            </ion-text>
          </ion-col>

          <ion-col
            id="times-item-stats"
            size="4"
            class="ion-text-end"
            v-if="getDayEntry(day)"
          >
            {{ formatDuration(getDayEntry(day).worktime) }}<br />
            <ion-text
              id="times-item-overtime"
              :color="switchOvertimeColor(getDayEntry(day).overtime)"
              >{{ getDayEntry(day).overtime.toString() }}</ion-text
            >
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="end">
      <ion-item-option
        id="times-item-delete-button"
        v-if="day.entry"
        ion-item-option
        color="danger"
        expandable
        @click="deleteEntryForDay(day)"
        >Delete</ion-item-option
      >
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
```

I'm doing end-to-end testing of the app with `cypress.io` but I can't get cypress to swipe the `ion-item-sliding` to the left side.

I tried it on the `ion-item-sliding` and also on the `ion-item` with various mouse events such as down, move, up, pointer. I also tried with touch event but nothing worked.

The last thing I tried was this test script:

`test typescript`

```
it("Delete today entry", () => {
    //GIVEN
    const today = new Date();
    const todayString: string = createItemSelectorTextForDate(today);

    //WHEN
    cy.get("#times-item-"+todayString)
    .trigger('mousedown', {force: true})
    .trigger('mousemove', {clientX: -80, force: true})
    .trigger('mouseup', {force: true});
})
```

Does Someone know how to get `cypress.io` to work with Ionic components```

Comment: See this thread. There seems to be no consistent solution. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1418

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with ion-item-sliding and after trying all the mouse, pointer, touch events that I can imagine nothing worked, but then I found 2 ways to click the hidden button.

### 1st solution

Faster one, click the hidden button directly:

```
 cy.get('ion-item-sliding.item-wrapper')
    .find('button[color="danger"]')
    .click({force:true});
```

This will not make the animation, the slider and button will not be visible but will call the button action.

### 2nd solution

Make the animation yourself. The events in the ion-item-sliding when swipe add a class and a style insertion.
Insert that with cypress:

```
cy.get('ion-item-sliding.item-wrapper')
   .invoke('addClass', 'active-slide active-options-right')
   .find('.item')
   .invoke('attr', 'style', 'transform: translate3d(-184px, 0px, 0px);')
```

The previous code was for *Ionic 3* for more new versions only need to change the classes.

###### Newest Ionic

Tested with latest [example code to date](https://ionic-docs-demo.herokuapp.com/component/item)

```
cy.get('ion-item-sliding')
    .invoke('addClass', 'item-sliding-active-slide item-sliding-active-options-end')
    .find('.item')
    .invoke('attr', 'style', 'transform: translate3d(-72px, 0px, 0px);')
```